# Wordpress Backend Emails using Ultimate Member Templates?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am using Ultimate Members plugin on my site for all user-related emails. And it works like a charm. Except for one minor, very annoying thing.

The emails I generate from Wordpress Backend does NOT use these templates.
In the user backend, when clicking on "Send password reset" WP goes ahead and use the default email template. Not only that, the link it provides is wrong and only provides users with a 404 error.

So my long question is: HOW on ******* am I to make WP use the UM templates when sending emails from the backend Users page ?

any smart php coders out there that can offer a quick'n dirty solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`send_retrieve_password_email`](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1790-send-um-reset-password-email-when-admin-send-password-reset-to-user?ssp=1&darkschemeovr=1&setlang=en&cc=CA&safesearch=moderate) filter to override the default WordPress password reset email with the Ultimate Member one. This will fetch the requested user's ID, then trigger a password reset email for the requested user.

```php
add_filter( 'send_retrieve_password_email', 'send_retrieve_password_email_custom', 10, 3 );

function send_retrieve_password_email_custom( $true, $user_login, $user_data ) {

    um_fetch_user( $user_data->ID );
    UM()->user()->password_reset();

    return false;
}
```

Add this to your `functions.php` file.